Create google cloud function
I've created a cloud function with a schedule. (I did that as a response to question I posted earlier). However, I realized that the schedule has no effect on the way the function runs. So instead of exporting schedule, I want to remove the schedule export and run it on a simple export base.
This is my code:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
const min = "*/5 * * * *";
exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule(min).onRun(async (context) => {
  const batch = database.batch();
  const {docs} = await database.collection("ADSGHANA").get();
  docs.map((doc) => {
    const {
      AdsId,
      UID,
      TimestampArrival,
      TimestampDeparture,
      PostStatus,
      TimeToDelete,
      StartingTime,
      EndingTime,
    } = doc.data();
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
    const starting = now > TimestampDeparture && now <= StartingTime;
    const ending = now > TimestampArrival && now <= EndingTime;
    const deleting = now > TimeToDelete;
    let val = PostStatus;
    if (starting && PostStatus !== "Cancelled") val = "Started";
    if (ending && PostStatus !== "Cancelled") val = "Completed";
   //.....the rest of my code
  await batch.commit();
});

My function is working well const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(); and as such the schedule of 15 minutes is no longer needed. How do I export my function without the schedule?

An example I saw on a different link

What do you mean by "run it on a simple export base"?  If you're not running in on a schedule, then how do you intend to run it at all?  All Cloud Functions require some triggering event that determines when it should run.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

@Doug Stevenson.  I don't really know because, in a field in my database, I have a Timestamp. And the function is that when the "const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();" get to the Timestamp, an update should occur. This happens very well whether or not the scheduled 15 minutes is up. That's why I thought the scheduled function is redundant.

If you don't have a triggering event, then Cloud Functions isn't the right product to use at all.  If you want to run some code just once, just use the Firebase Admin SDK with in a nodejs program that you run locally on your machine.

This is really complicated. I'm not using my personal server. I using Firebase as my backend. I have edited my question.
So in my function, I called "const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();"
So now the function is already running based on "now", and not based on "exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule(min).onRun(async (context)". Because the "scheduled" has no effect on "now". The "now" runs when it detects that the field "TimestampDeparture" = "now" regardless on whether the 15 minutes scheduled time is up or not. That's why I thought the export.schedule is redundant

That's why I want to know if there is another way of exporting but not using the "schedule" as in my export function. I've added an example of the code from a cloud function example I saw on the internet

If you want to run something just once, there is no option for that with Cloud Functions.  It's not the right tool for the job. Ignore Cloud Functions entirely and just write your program and run it locally with nodejs.

Ok. But I'm not an expect programmer. Could you please help me with that. I've never used node.js type of coding

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you want to run the code at a certain time that is determined by a dynamic value (such as the TimestampDeparture in the Firestore document in your screenshot), you'll want to use enqueue the function with Cloud Tasks rather than a CRON schedule.

Ok, Thanks. So it means I will now have to learn cloud tasks
